# SwiperJS AutoHeight doesn't seem to adjust height based on the elements inside of the container

Tags: html, swiper.js

I've been trying to learn how to use SwiperJS and one thing I have been struggling with is automatically resizing the swiper module according to the size of the screen (minus the navbar). I tried setting autoHeight to true, but when I add something inside of the swiper-wrapper, it gets stuck at a certain size.
How can I fix this?

Code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/Josh0531/62p8oLqy/67/

HTML:

```
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.css"
/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

<script type="module">
  import Swiper from 'https://unpkg.com/swiper@7/swiper-bundle.esm.browser.min.js'

  const swiper = new Swiper(...)
</script>

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">      
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</header>

<body class="scroll-stop">
<!-- Slider main container -->
<div class="swiper">
  <!-- Additional required wrapper -->
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <!-- Slides -->
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1
      <img src=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    ...
  </div>
  <!-- If we need pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
 <!--- <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>--->

  <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
</body>

<footer>
  This is a nice old div footer
  <br> INFO INFO
  <br> MORE INFO
  <br> Final Row
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  background-color: #083576;
  color: black;
} 

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none; 
      height: 100%}

.swiper {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
img  {
  height: 10px;
}
.scroll-stop {
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.swiper-pagination {
  left: 2px;
}
```